# Why is my HttpClient class freezing with certain URLs

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am currently getting to grips with new HttpClient libraries to come up with a basic class to return the html/css/etc. of requested URL.  Using the example taken from [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)

You can see the example below:

```
package test;

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class Test {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.cwjobs.co.uk/");
            System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

            // Create a response handler
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

            System.out.println(responseBody);
        } finally {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that if I was to set the URL I want to request to something like http://www.google.com then it prints out the response I need.  However, when I use a URL such as www.cwjobs.co.uk (used merely as an example) it freezes on the execute method.

I am fairly new to Java and I understand the basics of HTTP so I would love to know if:
 - Although I have used a basic example I have done it wrong by either missing something that needs to be added to access that specific URL
 - It is not possible to get the response I want from that specific URL due to environment setup on the Server side.
 - Any extra literature or links you can recommend for me to look over outside of the Apache.org site

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Have you run the request through a proxy to see if you can determine what's happening?

Comment: You might be missing a connection timeout.  Google returns fast/small pages.  Other sites might be much slower or broken.  See `http.socket.timeout`  in http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/preference-api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the timeout in DefaultHttpClient for the connection. See: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/CoreConnectionPNames.html?is-external=true#SO_TIMEOUT

Comment: Thanks for that.  Entering httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(1000)); got it to work!

Answer (score 1):

This code is now deprecated (get HttpParams, etc). A better way is:

```
RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.BEST_MATCH).setExpectContinueEnabled(true).setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(true).setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.NTLM, AuthSchemes.DIGEST)).setProxyPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.BASIC)).build();

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);    
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.copy(defaultRequestConfig).setSocketTimeout(5000).setConnectTimeout(5000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000).build();
httpGet.setConfig(requestConfig);
```

Comment: Why do you make a copy of the defaultRequestConfig rather than just use it?

Comment: There for illustration

Comment: ok, thanks. I thought perhaps there was a reason the default RequestConfig should not have timeouts set.